# Como pegar informações do banco de dados sem atualizar a página

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, banco-de-dados

Tenho um sistema em que ele pega informações do banco de dados. E esse banco de dados vai recebendo dados direto, então queria saber como pego esses dados e mostro na página, mas sem essa página ser atualizada.

Esse sistema está em php.

Comment: AJAX é o nome da tecnologia de carga assíncrona. Re: http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/beginners-guide-to-ajax-development-with-php

Comment: Se for muito frequente a atualização, usar websockets resulta em melhor performance e economia de recursos do que Ajax.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você precisará de ajax para isto, segue um exemplo minimalista:

```
$.ajax({
 url:'minha_pagina_acesso_banco.php', //sua página em php que retornará os dados
 type:'POST', // método post, GET ...
 data: 'param=1&param2=2', //seus paramêtros
 success: function(data){ // sucesso de retorno executar função
  $('#result').html(data); // adiciona o resultado na div #result
 }
});
```

Você pode executar essa função conforme ação do usuário, num intervalo de tempo, ao carregar a página e etc.

Para mais informações sobre o uso de **[jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)**

Answer (score 0):

**Recomendo usar GET no Jquery.**

```
$.get("minha_pagina_acesso_banco.php",
function(data){
   $('#result').html(data);
});
```

Como pode ver o codigo fica menor, pode enviar e receber dados assim.

mesma sintaxe para post, caso deseje enviar formulários, apenas muda-se o metodo.

```
$.post("minha_pagina_acesso_banco.php", 
function(data){
   $('#result').html(data);
});
```

**Confira em**

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/
http://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/

Para não recarregar a informação todas vezes que fizer a requisição, guarde em uma variável de sessão do PHP a data do ultimo update, desta forma sofrera alteração na tela todas vezes que fizer a requisição. apenas de echo na tela quando a data de inclusão/alteração for diferente.

```
$.get("minha_pagina_acesso_banco.php",
function(data){
   if(data!=''){
      $("#result").html($("#result").html()+data);
   }
});
```